# Can Windows Server 2008 R2 do backups to remote locations?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I have a WS2008 R2 box that does local backups of all my PCs, databases, etc.  I do replication to a few drives.  I want to be able to backup across the network, offsite, to say a drive at my office or home.  I can't find any documentation that does this.  Can WS2008 do this?  If so, can someone provide me with some documentation?  Otherwise I was thinking of setting up a local back up, creating a scheduler that calls a bat file witch then FTPs the file somewhere. Would that work?  I want to go this route only if there are no options with WS2008.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a backup job using [wbadmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015%28WS.10%29.aspx) specifically with the `-backuptarget` switch i.e. `-backuptarget:\\servername\sharename`

Unfortunately, `wbadmin` requires the share to be a UNC path, so other network storage filers are excluded. But really, did you want to push your backup across a network using FTP? Of *course* you didn't. When asking yourself "Can Windows backup to *$n* storage service?" reverse the question and ask "Can *$n* storage service be presented to Windows as a local drive or UNC path?" If the latter question can be answered in the affirmative, then you can use `wbadmin` to backup to it either locally or across the network.

If you're more into PowerShell (which anyone administering Windows boxxen should be), have a look at how to [add PowerShell cmdlets that can manage Windows Server backups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759156.aspx). There's [quite a gamut of them](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706683.aspx):

```
Add-WBBackupTarget
Add-WBBareMetalRecovery
Add-WBFileSpec
Add-WBSystemState
Add-WBVolume
Get-WBBackupSet
Get-WBBackupTarget
Get-WBBareMetalRecovery
Get-WBDisk
Get-WBFileSpec
Get-WBJob
Get-WBPolicy
Get-WBSchedule
Get-WBSummary
Get-WBSystemState
Get-WBVolume
Get-WBVssBackupOptions
New-WBBackupTarget
New-WBFileSpec
New-WBPolicy
Remove-WBBackupTarget
Remove-WBBareMetalRecovery
Remove-WBFileSpec
Remove-WBPolicy
Remove-WBSystemState
Remove-WBVolume
Set-WBPolicy
Set-WBSchedule
Set-WBVssBackupOptions
Start-WBBackup
```

It should be noted that the PowerShell cmdlets do not support backing up to removable media. You'll need to fall back on `wbadmin` for that. They do, however, support network targets.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I have lots to try out tomorrow.  As a side note is it possible to use these tools to also back up directly to something like S3?  Or do I still need to use a tool like gladinet and mount the drives to the cloud and have the backup service dump the files in those drives?

Comment: @northpole The Windows backup tool can only backup to a UNC path. You'll need to present your S3 bucket to the backup utility as a UNC path. So, that simplifies the possibilities. Whatever you have to do to access S3 as a UNC path is whatever you have to do.